# How long after Drupal 6 is out of support will Pressflow 6 be supported?

Tags: 6

We currently have a lot of D6 sites, and I'm wondering if Pressflow would make a decent "lifeboat" until I can get folks migrated to D7.

Obviously if PF6 goes out of support as soon as D6 does, than it won't be.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support request for Pressflow (fork of Drupal), and not Drupal itself. This should be asked at the appropriate place.

Comment: Where is the appropriate place?

Comment: I think this is fine here as long as we can get a definitive answer, or refer to a definitive answer.

Comment: While the question appears on-topic, I'd open a support request with pressflow's github project instead. You get much closer to the source that way. :)

Comment: I think [this thread](https://github.com/pressflow/6/issues/87) is appropriate place, there is an answer.